# Changing filter criteria in the new nav should send the user back to page 1

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

If I change filter criteria in the new nav (ie. adding a tag to filter by), it sends me to the same page # of the new search criteria as the page I was on before.

> 1. Start by looking at page 15 of the bounties list:
>      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/ending?page=15
> 2. Then, try to add a tag to filter by (type 'ios' and hit enter), you'll
>      be sent to:
>      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios?filter=bounties&sort=ending&page=15,
>      a query which has no results (at page 15).

Ideally, I would be sent to page 1, since theres no reason I'd want page 15 of a new query.